# symfony 2 form_row with 2 fields

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I need something like below:

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="form_row">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.field_name + '_previous') }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}
```

i.e, two form fields in one row; second field name is equal to first_field_name + _previous.
For example, if field name is 'total_cost', then second field will be 'total_cost_previous'.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do something like this:

```
{% set field = field_name ~ '_previous' %}
{{ form_widget(attribute(form, field)) }}
```

Comment: on the form row you cant do form.field_name + '_previous', you are passing already a form field to the form row. Your variable field_name_previous is a mapped field? Is it defined on the form type?